# What is a real world example for "smart pointer to member"?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, operators, smart-pointers

To clarify a possible precedence ambiguity in the English language: We are taking about "smart (pointer to member)", not "(smart pointer) to member".

I would define a *smart pointer to member* as a class X with `operator ->* (T* lhs, X rhs)` overloaded.

In his article ["Implementing operator->* for Smart Pointers"](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf), Scott Meyers only briefly touches ***smart*** pointer to member, because back then (1999) the specific problem was difficult enough for ***raw*** pointer to member (side note: the latter is solved elegantly with lambdas [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116654/overloading-operator-for-smart-pointers)).

Anyhow, Scott Meyers writes in a footnote:

> Shortly after writing the draft of this article, one of my consulting
>   clients showed me a problem that was naturally solved by smart pointers to members. I was surprised, too.

I've tried to find an example for such a natural *smart pointer to member*.
But I could neither come up with anything myself nor did online search uncover what I was looking for.

Do you know of any real world "smart pointer to member" example?

**EDIT**:
I'm not looking for any `->*` overload (as done by some EDSLs).
Aiming at examples with semantics that resemble the built-in `->*`, my definition above explicitly requires `lhs` to be a *raw pointer*.

Comment: Good call with the disambiguating preamble.

Comment: cppreference mentions that it's ".. in fact is used in that capacity by actors in boost.phoenix. It is more common in EDSLs such as cpp.react."

Comment: If we only could ask his consulting client ;)

Comment: Even here on SO is an interesting example https://stackoverflow.com/q/23619152/8918119. But none of them is really as smart pointer

Comment: In the cpp.react example `->*` is not used as *access through pointer to member*. They just used it in their EDSL and could have picked any other binary operator. It does not match my definition as `lhs` is not a raw pointer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2696864/8918119

Comment: Somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696664/about-shared-ptr-and-pointer-to-member-operator-and-stdbind

Answer (score 1):

You have a layout engine that should work with 90 degree rotation (height and width swapping).

Using smart member pointers you can make `(foo->*x)` and `(foo->*y)` swap meaning.  The same smart `x` and `y` can work on different unrelated kinds of data (rectangles, points, vectors), even on types you don't own.

```
template<class F>
struct smart_pm_t {
  F f;
  template<class T>
  friend decltype(auto) operator->*(T* t, smart_pm_t const& self ) {
    return self.f(t);
  }
};

template<class F>
smart_pm_t<F> smart_pm( F f ) { return {std::move(f)}; }

auto x = smart_pm( [](auto* t)->decltype(auto) noexcept { return t->x; } );
auto y = smart_pm( [](auto* t)->decltype(auto) noexcept { return t->y; } );
```

and we can get fancier with them.

```
do_layout( data, x, y );
```

vs

```
do_layout( data, y, x );
```

solves the problem horizontally or vertically.

This is an actual (simplified) use case in actual production code that reduced code duplication and ironed out a whole pile of bugs, because we only had to fix the code once.

A right hand normal member pointer had the problem that we would have to pass an entire suite of member pointers, one per type that works on the left hand side.

In effect, we wrote a compile-time polymorphic member pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful example @Yakk. Maybe I am missing something, but that looks to me like syntactic noise around a lambda call: As `do_layout` has to be a template anyway you could just do `auto get_x = [](auto* t)->decltype(auto) { return t->x; };` (note that the lambda is the same as yours), call `do_layout(data, get_x, get_y)` with `get_x(data)` instead of `data->*x` inside and thus more easily achieve the same thing. Or is it possible to motivate the use of `->*` by expanding the example (you mention that it is simplified)?

Comment: What is the motivation for overloading `->*` instead of just passing the accessor as a lambda? Would be really great if you could explain that! @Yakk

Comment: @tobi I am uncertain what you are asking.  Yes, every line of code can be rewritten differently.  `a+b` can always be rewritten as `f(a, b)` for any operator `+` or `f(b)(a)`.  In this case `x` behaves as a member pointer, using member pointer syntax makes sense.

Comment: overloading `+` is common, but `->*` is rarely used (even without overloading). So what's your story for writing the extra code? Historical (you used to have *raw* mem ptrs and refactored)? Same algorithms used both with *raw* and *smart* member ptrs? I'm just curious...